# Rails index action always returns null

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

So I am having an issue where I have this index action that is supposed to return json, but in the browser I am always getting a null response.

**Controller**

```
class Admin::Groups::UsersController < Admin::GroupsController
  def index
    @user_groups = Group.includes(:group_type, :users).where("group_types.group_type_name = ?", 'Users').order("groups.group_name ASC")

    render json: @user_groups.to_json(:include => [:group_type, :users], :methods => :enabled)
  end

  def show
    @user_group = Group.includes(:group_type, :users).where("group_types.group_type_name = ?", 'Users').find_by_id(params[:id])

    render json: @user_group.to_json(:include => [:group_type, :users], :methods => :enabled)
  end
end
```

**Route file**

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :groups do
    resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
      get 'enabled', :on => :collection
      get 'disabled', :on => :collection
    end
  end
end
```

**Output of rake routes**

```
admin_groups_users GET    /admin/groups/users(.:format)                   admin/groups/users#index
```

What is really throwing me off is that when I run the same code that is inside the index action in the rails console, it is outputting exactly what I expected. Also the show action works fine. And just for testing, I added a new route that I just called `index2` and copied + pasted the code from the `index` action into `index2` and I got the correct output in the browser.

So it has to be something to do with my route, but I'm not sure what it is?

**Edit 1: Add entire output of rake routes**

```
enabled_admin_accounts GET    /admin/accounts/enabled(.:format)               admin/accounts#enabled

disabled_admin_accounts GET    /admin/accounts/disabled(.:format)              admin/accounts#disabled

account_owners_admin_accounts GET    /admin/accounts/account_owners(.:format)  admin/accounts#account_owners

admin_accounts GET    /admin/accounts(.:format)                       admin/accounts#index

admin_account GET    /admin/accounts/:id(.:format)                   admin/accounts#show

enabled_admin_users GET    /admin/users/enabled(.:format)                  admin/users#enabled

disabled_admin_users GET    /admin/users/disabled(.:format)                 admin/users#disabled

admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                          admin/users#index

admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#show
enabled_admin_owners GET    /admin/owners/enabled(.:format)                 admin/owners#enabled

disabled_admin_owners GET    /admin/owners/disabled(.:format)                admin/owners#disabled

currencies_admin_owner GET    /admin/owners/:id/currencies(.:format)          admin/owners#currencies

admin_owners GET    /admin/owners(.:format)                         admin/owners#index

admin_owner GET    /admin/owners/:id(.:format)                     admin/owners#show

enabled_admin_counterparties GET    /admin/counterparties/enabled(.:format)         admin/counterparties#enabled

disabled_admin_counterparties GET    /admin/counterparties/disabled(.:format)        admin/counterparties#disabled

admin_counterparties GET    /admin/counterparties(.:format)                 admin/counterparties#index

admin_counterparty GET    /admin/counterparties/:id(.:format)             admin/counterparties#show

enabled_admin_venues GET    /admin/venues/enabled(.:format)                 admin/venues#enabled

disabled_admin_venues GET    /admin/venues/disabled(.:format)                admin/venues#disabled

admin_venues GET    /admin/venues(.:format)                         admin/venues#index

admin_venue GET    /admin/venues/:id(.:format)                     admin/venues#show

enabled_admin_custody_banks GET    /admin/custody_banks/enabled(.:format)          admin/custody_banks#enabled

disabled_admin_custody_banks GET    /admin/custody_banks/disabled(.:format)         admin/custody_banks#disabled

admin_custody_banks GET    /admin/custody_banks(.:format)                  admin/custody_banks#index

admin_custody_bank GET    /admin/custody_banks/:id(.:format)              admin/custody_banks#show

enabled_admin_client_currencies GET    /admin/client_currencies/enabled(.:format)      admin/client_currencies#enabled

disabled_admin_client_currencies GET    /admin/client_currencies/disabled(.:format)     admin/client_currencies#disabled

admin_client_currencies GET    /admin/client_currencies(.:format)              admin/client_currencies#index

admin_client_currency GET    /admin/client_currencies/:id(.:format)          admin/client_currencies#show

admin_currencies        /admin/currencies(.:format)                     admin/client_currencies#index

admin_all_currencies        /admin/all_currencies(.:format)                 admin/currencies#index

enabled_admin_groups GET    /admin/groups/enabled(.:format)                 admin/groups#enabled

disabled_admin_groups GET    /admin/groups/disabled(.:format)                admin/groups#disabled

admin_groups GET    /admin/groups(.:format)                         admin/groups#index

admin_group GET    /admin/groups/:id(.:format)                     admin/groups#show

enabled_admin_groups_accounts GET    /admin/groups/accounts/enabled(.:format)        admin/groups/accounts#enabled

disabled_admin_groups_accounts GET    /admin/groups/accounts/disabled(.:format)       admin/groups/accounts#disabled

admin_groups_accounts GET    /admin/groups/accounts(.:format)                admin/groups/accounts#index

admin_groups_account GET    /admin/groups/accounts/:id(.:format)            admin/groups/accounts#show

enabled_admin_groups_account_owners GET    /admin/groups/account_owners/enabled(.:format)  admin/groups/account_owners#enabled

disabled_admin_groups_account_owners GET    /admin/groups/account_owners/disabled(.:format) admin/groups/account_owners#disabled

admin_groups_account_owners GET    /admin/groups/account_owners(.:format)          admin/groups/account_owners#index

admin_groups_account_owner GET    /admin/groups/account_owners/:id(.:format)      admin/groups/account_owners#show

enabled_admin_groups_users GET    /admin/groups/users/enabled(.:format)           admin/groups/users#enabled

disabled_admin_groups_users GET    /admin/groups/users/disabled(.:format)          admin/groups/users#disabled

admin_groups_users GET    /admin/groups/users(.:format)                   admin/groups/users#index

admin_groups_user GET    /admin/groups/users/:id(.:format)               admin/groups/users#show

enabled_admin_groups_counterparties GET    /admin/groups/counterparties/enabled(.:format)  admin/groups/counterparties#enabled

disabled_admin_groups_counterparties GET    /admin/groups/counterparties/disabled(.:format) admin/groups/counterparties#disabled

admin_groups_counterparties GET    /admin/groups/counterparties(.:format)          admin/groups/counterparties#index

admin_groups_counterparty GET    /admin/groups/counterparties/:id(.:format)      admin/groups/counterparties#show

enabled_admin_groups_currencies GET    /admin/groups/currencies/enabled(.:format)      admin/groups/currencies#enabled

disabled_admin_groups_currencies GET    /admin/groups/currencies/disabled(.:format)     admin/groups/currencies#disabled

admin_groups_currencies GET    /admin/groups/currencies(.:format)              admin/groups/currencies#index

admin_groups_currency GET    /admin/groups/currencies/:id(.:format)          admin/groups/currencies#show

root        /                                               trades#index

jasminerice        /jasmine                                        Jasminerice::Engine
```

Comment: resources :users, :only => [:index,:show],:collection => {:enabled => :get,:prepare => :get} can you change you route to this and check if it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this route further down the route list.

```
admin_group GET    /admin/groups/:id(.:format)                     admin/groups#show
```

The route list is searched in-order. `/admin/groups/users` is matching this route with `:id` equal to `users`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, this was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

`render` is either in the form

```
render :json => @user_groups
```

in which it calls `to_json` for you and it cannot pass arguments, or you can do this:

```
format.json { render @user_groups.to_json(:include => [:group_type, :users], :methods => :enabled) }
```

If you *always* want to return json no matter what `format` is, then just get rid of the `json:` thing:

```
render @user_groups.to_json(:include => [:group_type, :users], :methods => :enabled)
```

Comment: No, that didn't seem to fix it. I don't believe the issue is in the controller since my show action is working and it is using the same exact code as my index action (with the exception of the find_by_id part). also I mentioned in my post that I created a index2 action with the same code and that did work, so it must be a route issue, unless I am missing something

Comment: Then please post the entirety of your `rake routes` output.

Comment: Ok, I just posed it. Also I discovered something interesting. I commented out all of my code inside my index action. And when I refreshed the browser it still just said `null` in the browser and I did not receive a `Template is missing` error. (I tried restarting rails server and clearing cache and still had same results)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your routes to this and check

```
namespace :admin do
        namespace :groups do
          resources :users, :only => [:index,:show],:collection => {:enabled => :get,:disabled => :get}
        end
      end
```

Comment: Still getting `null` in the browser window